# Text analyzer Matlab

Tags: matlab, text, analyzer

I'm working on a text analyzer using `Matlab`, which reads a `.txt` file and find out what is it talking about (Subject), let's say i have a list of words : `{'SVM','Linear','SVMTRAIN','Vector', 'Support'..};`
when reading my text file i want to find if it contains this words and displays something like 'This file talks about SVM...'; else it doesn't.
i'm really confused i tried getting words freq and now i'm stuck any help!
my code :

```
fid = fopen('Test.txt');
s=textscan(fid,'%s')
fclose(fid);
str=s{:}

[unique_words,jj,kk] = unique(str)
freq = hist(kk,(1:numel(jj))).'
d = [unique_words num2cell(freq)]
```

text file example:

```
Kernel-based techniques (such as support vector machines, Bayes point
machines, kernel principal component analysis, and Gaussian processes) represent
a major development in machine learning algorithms. Support vector
machines (SVM) are a group of supervised learning methods that can be
applied to classification or regression. In a short period of time, SVM found
numerous applications in chemistry, such as in drug design (discriminating
between ligands and nonligands, inhibitors and noninhibitors, etc.), quantitative
structure-activity relationships (QSAR, where SVM regression is used to
predict various physical, chemical, or biological properties), chemometrics
(optimization of chromatographic separation or compound concentration prediction
from spectral data as examples), sensors (for qualitative and quantitative
prediction from sensor data), chemical engineering (fault detection and
modeling of industrial processes), and text mining (automatic recognition of
scientific information).
Support vector machines represent an extension to nonlinear models of the
generalized portrait algorithm developed by Vapnik and Lerner.
```

Comment: Can you post a sample `Test.txt` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to do it using regular expressions. I'm sure there is a more efficient way to do it, but I use a loop to check for matches in the text file with every word in your list of words. I hope that won't be too long for your application. Anyhow here is the code:

```
clear
clc

%// Generate dummy text document, equivalent to what you would get after
%// the call to s{:}.
str = {'Blablabla';'SVM';'SuPPorT';'Vector';'DummyWord';'Hello there';'SVM';'Vector';'Support'};


WordList = cell(2,5);
WordList(1,:) = {'SVM','Linear','SVMTRAIN','Vector', 'Support'};

for k = 1:size(WordList,2)
   %// Use regular expressions to match each word in your list in the text
   CheckWord = regexp(str,WordList{1,k},'match');

   %// Find indices in which there is a match in the text.
   MatchCells = ~cellfun(@isempty,CheckWord);

   %// Count the number of occurences for future reference.
   NumOccurences = numel(find(MatchCells));

   %// Assign number of occurences as 2nd row of WordList cell array
   WordList{2,k} = num2str(NumOccurences);

end
%// Display WordList
WordList
```

`WordList` looks like this:

```
WordList = 

    'SVM'    'Linear'    'SVMTRAIN'    'Vector'    'Support'
    '2'      '0'         '0'           '2'         '1'
```

That would thus be easy to display the number of matches for each word.

Hope that helps!

**EDIT**
Here are a few additional explanations about Matchcells and NumOccurences:

1) MatchCells returns a vector of logical values (i.e 0 or 1) corresponding to whether (1) or not (0) a given cell in a cell array is empty. Here the cell array in question is `CheckWord`, and for each word in the list of words defined above, we check with regexp their position in `str`.  Using `cellfun` operates on a whole cell array and is equivalent to a for-loop. For example in the loop above, for k = 1, `MatchCells` looks like this:

```
MatchCells =

     0
     1
     0
     0
     0
     0
     1
     0
     0
```

Therefore, we see that the 2nd and 7th entry of `CheckWord` is not empty for the 1st word in the list (SVM). Note that I used `~cellfun(...)` to denote cells that were not empty. For empty cells I would have used `cellfun(...)`. Then `NumOccurences` denotes the number of 1's in MatchCells, here 2 for the case of the word `SVM`.

To make it clearer, `find(MatchCells)` returns the indices in the cell array which correspond to matches. If there is no match, the answer is zero. Using `numel(find(MatchCells))` gives us the number of element in the array resulting form the `find` command, thus giving the number of matches.

If you want to see better what every line does, remove the semi-colon (;) at the end so that you will get the output in the command window.

Comment: Can you explain these 2 code lines : 
























    `%// Find indices in which there is a match in the text.
   MatchCells = ~cellfun(@isempty,CheckWord);

   %// Count the number of occurences for futuere reference.
   NumOccurences = numel(find(MatchCells));`
i didn't understand what does MatchCells returns, And how NumOccurences also !

Comment: so what does is mean :  `numel(find(MatchCells));`

Comment: thanks for all, just one more question if u don't mind, what if my WorldList Contains these elements :
`WroldsList ={'svm hello','non linear','svmtrain','vector support','kernel','machine','soft classification'};`

How do i compare my Text file with this new WordList which contains **String** `('svm hello','vector support','soft classification')` not just **Words**

Comment: the problem is that i'm spliting my Text file using this code:
`%{  Read Text File  %}
text = fileread('Text_File.txt'); 
s = regexp(text,'\w*','match');` 

so when i execute your code i don't get results when i comes to String like **'svm hello'** or **'non linear'**.. any ideas ?
                 **0**              **0**